# Unable to import module 'Import-certificate': No module named '_cffi_backend'

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm getting this error in my lambda after updating python 3.8 to python 3.9
I have the following module in the requirements.txt file:

```
boto3
botocore
pycparser
pyopenssl
certifi
```

I'm suspecting this issue is happening because of pyopenssl ... any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The Error is mainly related to lambda layers.

As you mentioned in question, you have upgraded the Python version from 3.8 to 3.9.

If all the modules were working perfectly in Python 3.8, then the issue is related to the different versions of the AWS Lambda function and the Python function that you used to create the lambda layer.

The lambda layer is being created with version 3.8, and you are trying to access it with version 3.9

Can you update the lambda layer Python version and try again?

---

Update: Python lambda layer can be created by following 2 directory structure.
[image: Directory structure]

You must have used second directory structure, which can cause this issue.

AWS Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/packaging-layers.html#packaging-layers-paths